# Cannot retrieve original image using FFT with FFTW

Tags: c, valgrind, fftw

I'm using FFTW in my C code and I have some issue.
First, I can transform an original image to two images (mag+phase) and get back the original image with the inverse transform.
However, If I want to get a mag file centered in frequency it does not work anymore: the final image has some issues.

Here some pieces of my code. Can someone help me to find the error in my code?

EDIT: I've fixed the code to follow @francis recommandation, but my issues is always here.

```
enum {
    TYPE_CENTERED,
    TYPE_REGULAR
};

static void fft_to_spectra(fits* fit, fftw_complex *frequency_repr, double *as,
        double *ps, int nbdata) {
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < nbdata; i++) {
        double r = creal(frequency_repr[i]);
        double im = cimag(frequency_repr[i]);
        as[i] = hypot(r, im);
        ps[i] = atan2(im, r);
    }
}

static void fft_to_freq(fits* fit, fftw_complex *frequency_repr, double *as, double *ps, int nbdata) {
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < nbdata; i++) {
        frequency_repr[i] = as[i] * (cos(ps[i]) + I * sin(ps[i]));
    }
}

void change_symmetry(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int i, unsigned int j, unsigned int *x,
        unsigned int *y) {

    if (i < width / 2 && j < height / 2) {
        *x = i + width / 2;
        *y = j + height / 2;
    }
    if (i >= width / 2 && j < height / 2) {
        *x = i - width / 2;
        *y = j + height / 2;
    }
    if (i < width / 2 && j >= height / 2) {
        *x = i + width / 2;
        *y = j - height / 2;
    }
    if (i >= width / 2 && j >= height / 2) {
        *x = i - width / 2;
        *y = j - height / 2;
    }
}

static void centered(WORD *buf, unsigned int width,
        unsigned int height) {
    unsigned int i, j;

    WORD *temp = malloc(width * height * sizeof(WORD));
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            unsigned int x = i;
            unsigned int y = j;
            change_symmetry(width, height, i, j, &x, &y);

            temp[j * width + i] = buf[y * width + x];
        }
    }

    memcpy(buf, temp, sizeof(WORD) * width * height);
    free(temp);
}

static void normalisation_spectra(unsigned int w, unsigned int h, double *modulus, double *phase,
        WORD *abuf, WORD *pbuf) {
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < h * w; i++) {
        pbuf[i] = round_to_WORD(((phase[i] + M_PI) * USHRT_MAX_DOUBLE / (2 * M_PI)));
        abuf[i] = round_to_WORD((modulus[i] / w / h));
    }
}

static void save_dft_information_in_gfit(fits *fit) {
    strcpy(gfit.dft.ord, fit->dft.type);
    strcpy(gfit.dft.ord, fit->dft.ord);
}

static void FFTD(fits *fit, fits *x, fits *y, int type_order, int layer) {
    WORD *xbuf = x->pdata[layer];
    WORD *ybuf = y->pdata[layer];
    WORD *gbuf = fit->pdata[layer];
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int width = fit->rx, height = fit->ry;
    int nbdata = width * height;

    fftw_complex *spatial_repr = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nbdata);
    if (!spatial_repr) {
        return;
    }
    fftw_complex *frequency_repr = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nbdata);
    if (!frequency_repr) {
        fftw_free(spatial_repr);
        return;
    }

    /* copying image selection into the fftw data */
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(com.max_thread) private(i) schedule(static) if(nbdata > 15000)
#endif
    for (i = 0; i < nbdata; i++) {
        spatial_repr[i] = (double) gbuf[i];
    }

    /* we run the Fourier Transform */
    fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(height, width, spatial_repr, frequency_repr,
            FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);

    /* we compute modulus and phase */
    double *modulus = malloc(nbdata * sizeof(double));
    double *phase = malloc(nbdata * sizeof(double));

    fft_to_spectra(fit, frequency_repr, modulus, phase, nbdata);

    //We normalize the modulus and the phase
    normalisation_spectra(width, height, modulus, phase, xbuf, ybuf);
    if (type_order == TYPE_CENTERED) {
        strcpy(x->dft.ord, "CENTERED");
        centered(xbuf, width, height);
        centered(ybuf, width, height);
    }

    free(modulus);
    free(phase);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(spatial_repr);
    fftw_free(frequency_repr);
}

static void FFTI(fits *fit, fits *xfit, fits *yfit, int type_order, int layer) {
    WORD *xbuf = xfit->pdata[layer];
    WORD *ybuf = yfit->pdata[layer];
    WORD *gbuf = fit->pdata[layer];
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int width = xfit->rx;
    unsigned int height = xfit->ry;
    int nbdata = width * height;

    double *modulus = calloc(1, nbdata * sizeof(double));
    double *phase = calloc(1, nbdata * sizeof(double));

    if (type_order == TYPE_CENTERED) {
        centered(xbuf, width, height);
        centered(ybuf, width, height);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < height * width; i++) {
        modulus[i] = (double) xbuf[i] * (width * height);
        phase[i] = (double) ybuf[i] * (2 * M_PI / USHRT_MAX_DOUBLE);
        phase[i] -= M_PI;
    }

    fftw_complex* spatial_repr = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nbdata);
    if (!spatial_repr) {
        return;
    }

    fftw_complex* frequency_repr = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nbdata);
    if (!frequency_repr) {
        fftw_free(spatial_repr);
        return;
    }

    fft_to_freq(fit, frequency_repr, modulus, phase, nbdata);

    fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(height, width, frequency_repr, spatial_repr,
            FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);

    for (i = 0; i < nbdata; i++) {
        double pxl = creal(spatial_repr[i]) / nbdata;
        gbuf[i] = round_to_WORD(pxl);
    }

    free(modulus);
    free(phase);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(spatial_repr);
    fftw_free(frequency_repr);
}
```

Here my images, the original one and the FFTD(centered)->FFTI result
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plan is created using the flag `FFTW_MEASURE`. Hence, several DFT are computed and the input array is likely overwritten. Here is the start of the description of planner flags in the [documentation of FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Planner-Flags.html):

> - `FFTW_ESTIMATE` specifies that, instead of actual measurements of different algorithms, a simple heuristic is used to pick a (probably sub-optimal) plan quickly. **With this flag, the input/output arrays are not overwritten during planning.**
> - `FFTW_MEASURE` tells FFTW to find an optimized plan by actually computing several FFTs and measuring their execution time. Depending on your machine, this can take some time (often a few seconds). FFTW_MEASURE is the default planning option.

Either switch to `FFTW_ESTIMATE` or create the plan before populating the input array:

```
/* we run the Fourier Transform */
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_2d(width, height, spatial_repr, frequency_repr,
        FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);

/* copying image selection into the fftw data */
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(com.max_thread) private(i) schedule(static) if(nbdata > 15000)
#endif
for (i = 0; i < nbdata; i++) {
    spatial_repr[i] = (double) gbuf[i];
}
```

If you intend to a single image, using `FFTW_ESTIMATE` is the way to go. On the contrary, if you consider treating multiple images, creating the plan once using `FFTW_MEASURE` and storing it is a good option. Then you may use [New-array Execute Functions](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/New_002darray-Execute-Functions.html#New_002darray-Execute-Functions) each time a FFT is to be performed:

```
fftw_execute_dft(p, spatial_repr, frequency_repr);
```

You can test the return value of `malloc()` or `fftw_malloc()` to check if the allocations went right. If not, it returns `NULL`. `fftw_malloc()` is implemented as function `*X(kernel_malloc)(size_t n)` in fftw-3.3.6-pl2/kernel/kalloc.c . It calls functions like [`memalign()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign) or [`_aligned_malloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-malloc?view=vs-2019) among others. Both these two return `NULL` just like `malloc()` in case of failure. Finally, I did not spotted a critical issue regarding memory allocation of deallocation in the piece of code you provided.

The argument `double nbdata` in `fft_to_spectra()` should likely be an integer. Valgrind might have considered it as strange...

EDIT : the `change_symmetry()` is to be modified for odd sizes. Something like:

```
void change_symmetry_forward(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int i, unsigned int j, unsigned int *x,
    unsigned int *y) {
     *x = i + width / 2;
     if (*x>=width){
           *x=*x-width;
     }
     *y = j + height / 2;
     if(*y>=height){
          *y =*y-height;
     }
}
```

and

```
void change_symmetry_backward(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, unsigned int i, unsigned int j, unsigned int *x,
    unsigned int *y) {
     *x = i +width- width / 2;
     if (*x>=width){
           *x=*x-width;
     }
     *y = j +height- height / 2;
     if(*y>=height){
          *y =*y-height;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did follow your recommendation. However memory error is always here and the final image is not exactly like the original one. But if I choose the Regular view, it is ok. Is there an error in change_symmetry?

Comment: You're welcome! You can try to apply `change_symmetry()` twice, something like `change_symmetry(fit, i, j, &x, &y);change_symmetry(fit, x, y, &ii, &jj);` and test for differences `if(ii !=  i || jj!= j){...}` and test for bound infrigments `if(x>=width){...}` This function looks right, but it mixes unsigned and signed integers.

Comment: Ok thanks. One question though: when my input image is non square. What is the best way to make padding  ?  I'm wondering if my issue is not because of it.

Comment: The inverse DFT of the DFT of the padded image is to be identical to the padded image. Nevertheless, padding likely affect the computed magnitude and phases. If an uniform image is padded with zeros, spurous frequencies appears due to the artificial discontinuity on the padded image. If you are interrested by the magnitude of the different frequencies, [applying a 2D window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) such as the Tukey window could limit the consequences of [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage).

Comment: Spectral leakage occurs as soon as the image is not a periodic pattern. If you periodize a smooth image like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Grey_icon.svg), the white part on top is right next the dark part near the bottom. This sharp edge induces large magnitude for high frequencies. A 2D window would smoothly turn all edges to dark and avoid such sharp edges.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. Can I work with non square image and get a non square magnitude image ? It seems ok with Octave but not with my code.

Comment: no more valgrind error but always my issue in centered FFT

Comment: Thanks for the images. Indeed, you don't have to pad the image to perform the treatment and the magnitude will not be impaired by spectral leakage as your image decreases to zero near all boundaries.  It looks like the mean value is ok, the high frequencies are ok, but low frequencies are cleared or reduced. It could be triggered by an overflow here `abuf[i] = round_to_WORD((modulus[i] / w / h));`. Despite the scaling by w*h, the first frequencies likely display magnitudes higher than `USHRT_MAX_DOUBLE`.

Comment: My image dimension is 569x261 pixels. If I crop one pixel to have 568x260 pixels it works .... Do you understand why ? Again, with no "centering" it works all the time

Comment: Indeed, if you do what `change_symmetry` does for odd number like 7,  the index 3 is affected twice and index 6 is never affected... The shift must be identical for all frequencies, it is +width/2-width if above width. It's different from -width/2 for odd numbers! And the reverse shift is not identical to the forward shift for odd numbers, because width/2+width/2 !=width  !!!

Comment: Any idea of what I can do ?

Comment: I added to the answer an hint showing how it could be implemented.

Comment: Last question. Do you think my normalisation is bad and lead to overflow as you said before ? should I normalize by the max value of frequency ?

Comment: The overflow is possible, take a look at `cos(x)-0.2*cos(3*x)` for instance. This function remains strickly between -1 and 1, but its first frequency is of magniude 1.Indeed, normalizing by the max amplitude solves it and improves the accuracy, but the normalization factor is to be stored somewhere.